# easy way to just print the man page intro or description

Tags: man

Is there an easy way to quickly view a condensed summary of a man page: just the description description, or intro? I don't see an option/flag that does this, is there another tool that does this for you?

Answer (score 6):

The *condensed summary* referred to by OP is likely the *NAME* section, which is treated specially by [`mandb`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mandb.8.html) or `makewhatis` (to prepare data for [`whatis`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whatis.1.html) and [`apropos`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html).

By convention, this is a single line in those tools (although it may be wrapped due to length in the actual manpage).  Also (still convention), there is a dash between the topic (on the left) and the short description.

Further reading (Linux):

- [Linux manual page for `man(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) has more than one useful option using this data:

> **`man -k`** *printf*
>   Search the short descriptions and manual page names for the
>   keyword *printf* as regular expression.  Print out any matches.
>   Equivalent to **`apropos printf`**.
>
> **`man -f`** *smail*
>   Lookup the manual pages referenced by `smail` and print out the
>   short descriptions of any found.  Equivalent to **`whatis smail`**.

The `apropos` listing gives more results since it shows matches on any part of the line in the short description.  For example, `apropos printf` might show

```
asprintf (3)         - print to allocated string
dprintf (3)          - print to a file descriptor
fprintf (3)          - formatted output conversion
fwprintf (3)         - formatted wide-character output conversion
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
snprintf (3)         - formatted output conversion
sprintf (3)          - formatted output conversion
swprintf (3)         - formatted wide-character output conversion
vasprintf (3)        - print to allocated string
vdprintf (3)         - print to a file descriptor
vfprintf (3)         - formatted output conversion
vfwprintf (3)        - formatted wide-character output conversion
vprintf (3)          - formatted output conversion
vsnprintf (3)        - formatted output conversion
vsprintf (3)         - formatted output conversion
vswprintf (3)        - formatted wide-character output conversion
vwprintf (3)         - formatted wide-character output conversion
wprintf (3)          - formatted wide-character output conversion
XtAsprintf (3)       - memory management functions
```

But `whatis` looks for pages with the given topic name:

```
printf (1)           - format and print data  
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
```

- [Linux manual page for `man-pages(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html) describes the structure.

Other systems can differ:

- [OSX manual page for `man(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html), option  `-k` is equivalent to [`apropos`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/apropos.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/apropos).  In turn, `apropos` *DESCRIPTION* says "apropos  searches  a  set of database files containing short descriptions of system commands for key-words keywords words and displays the result on the standard output.", while its *NAME* section says "apropos - search the whatis database for strings".
- [OSX manual page for `manpages(5)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html) gives the structure of manpages.

While the `man` program in each case can have options corresponding to `apropos` and `whatis`, the separate programs are more commonly used across various Unix-like systems.

Interestingly, POSIX has only [`man`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/man.html) (and the `-k` option), with no match for `whatis`.  In the rationale, it is noted

> The **`-f`** option was considered, but due to implementation differences, it was not included in this volume of POSIX.1-2008.

Also, POSIX does not use the term *apropos*, but describes it.  Likewise POSIX does not (in that section, at least) attempt to describe the structure of individual manpages nor how they are organized into sections.  Those are system-dependent features.

Answer (score 5):

These couple of functions show subsection and extract specific subsection, I'm sure they can be improved though:

Use:

mansubs < command >
manedit < command > < subsection >

```
mansubs() {
 man "$1" |col -bx|awk '/^[A-Z ]+$/ {print}'
}

manedit() {
 man "$1" |col -bx|awk -v S="$2" '$0 ~ S {cap="true"; print} $0 !~ S && /^[A-Z ]+$/ {cap="false"} $0 !~ S && !/^[A-Z ]+$/ {if(cap == "true")print}'
}
```

For instance:

```
$ mansubs grep
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
REGULAR EXPRESSIONS
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
EXIT STATUS
COPYRIGHT
BUGS
SEE ALSO
NOTES

$ manedit grep SYNOPSIS
SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
       grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

Comment: Would love to hear more about how this works

Answer (score 2):

Some commands support `--help or -h' which can give brief usage.

For specifically the man pages, I would suggest as an "easy" way is

```
man | head -15 #Number of lines can be different for each man page
```

There are some other ways, such as writing a small function and setting as an alias.

Something to get you started:

```
function readManDesc() {
manPage="$1"
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
count="10"
else
count="$2"
fi
man $manPage | grep -A$count "^DESCRIPTION" #This will get the DESCRIPTION + the 10 lines that come after.
}

readManDesc $@
```

> alias mandesc="bash manPageDesc.sh"

```
Usage: mandesc <command> <lines to count after DESCRIPTION>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by "description", [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) has an option:

```
-f, --whatis
      Equivalent to whatis.  Display a short description from the man‐
      ual page, if available.  See whatis(1) for details.
```

So:

```
$ man -f man                                   
man (7)              - macros to format man pages
man (1)              - an interface to the on-line reference manuals
man (1p)             - display system documentation
$ whatis man 
man (7)              - macros to format man pages
man (1)              - an interface to the on-line reference manuals
man (1p)             - display system documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean just the description part of the man page before getting into the command line switches

```
man <command> | col -b > /tmp/randomtempfile
```

then using `grep` and `sed` you can extract however much information you need from the `randomtempfile`. As far as I know, man doesn't have an option to display summary pages.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like below.

```
man <command> | grep -a1 "NAME\|Description"; echo ""
```

PS: The echo "" at the end is just added to add a newline at the end of output for cleaner output :)